# PHP Query comes back as 'Array' instead of a name from database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database, wordpress

I have the following query:

```
$name = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT appname FROM `$table_db_name` WHERE ID = '$ID' ", OBJECT);
```

Every of these values are correct and when I query it to the database it returns me an array with 1 option.

When I echo `$name` its result is: 'Array',  while in the database it says: 'Succesful'

It should mention 'Succesful test' as echo and not 'Array'

Comment: Try `var_dump($name)` for test. Maybe you don't use function like `mysql_fetch_array`?

Comment: From the documentation - `[get_results] returns the entire query result as an array`. So you might need to parse `$name` to get the field you need. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#13 (1) { ["appname"]=> string(15) "Succesful test" } } ` is the result, but how do I only get  1 item, since it's based on getting only 1 item and not multiple so it doesn't need an array. @andrewsi I'm fairly new to all this stuff, how do I do this?

Comment: @Thovex - I _think_ you can access it with $name[0]->['appname']

Comment: @andrewsi `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\atheme\functions.php on line 231` this is the result, if I try just `echo $name[0];` it mentions: `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\atheme\functions.php on line 231`

Comment: @Thovex - see Richard Christensen's answer. Darn, but I'm rustier with objects than I thought.

Comment: @Thovex - What you could have done instead of `$name[0]->['appname']` was `$name[0]->appname` that should work as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**Edit**:
Since i didn't notice that you were using Wordpress, one thing you can do.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT appname FROM $table_db_name WHERE ID= '$ID' "), OBJECT);
if(!empty($result)){
  var_dump($result->appname);
}
```

You can also use `$wpdb->get_var()` instead of `$wpdb->get_row()` to fetch only the appname and not have to worry about using arrays.

```
$app_name = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT appname FROM $table_db_name WHERE ID =      '$ID' "), OBJECT);
if(!empty($app_name)){
var_dump($app_name);
}
```

more information found here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14239/wpdb-get-row-only-returns-a-single-row

Comment: Scratch that, your previous comment has gotten it right, thanks.